# In-App billing with BillingClient. ResponceCode = -1. Service connection is disconnected

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-billing

In my application, a donation function was made. (The application with permission to purchase inside the application is available in google play and in the downloaded version, this function works) I did it using the easy library from **anjlab**. I started to update the application, and rewrote it at the same time on **Kotlin**. Donat stopped working for some reason. I decided to redo the code from the **anjlab** library to the new billing library from google. When I try to make a purchase, I get

> responseCode = -1 (service connection is disconnected).

I tried to resume the connection using `startConnection` (this), tried to change the version in the **gradle**, loaded the new version into the library **apk**. Neither the old nor the new does not work (if you download from google play, the one that is published, it works). Code wrote on the guideline from Google. I test the application signed on a real device

**SettingsFramgent.kt** (only sacrament code)

```
package *

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.preference.Preference

import com.starikov.datecalc.R

class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat(), SettingsContract.View {

    private lateinit var presenter: SettingsContract.Presenter

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey)

        presenter = SettingsPresenter(activity!!)
        presenter.attachView(this)

val makeDonatePref: Preference = findPreference(MAKE_DONATE_KEY)!!

        makeDonatePref.setOnPreferenceClickListener { presenter.makeDonateClicked(); true }

        presenter.viewIsReady()
    }

    override fun showToast(resId: Int) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, resId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    override fun startActivity(intent: Intent) {
        activity!!.startActivity(intent)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        presenter.detachView()
        if (activity!!.isFinishing) {
            presenter.destroy()
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val MAKE_DONATE_KEY = "make_donate"
    }
}
```

**SettingsPresenter.kt**

```
package *

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import com.android.billingclient.api.*

import com.starikov.datecalc.common.PresenterBase
import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClient
import com.android.billingclient.api.SkuDetailsParams
import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingFlowParams
import com.starikov.datecalc.R
import java.util.*


internal class SettingsPresenter internal constructor(private val activity: Activity)
    : PresenterBase<SettingsContract.View>(), SettingsContract.Presenter {
    private lateinit var billingClient: BillingClient
    private var skuDetailsMap: HashMap<String, SkuDetails> = HashMap()

    override fun makeDonateClicked() {
        initBillingProcessor()
        launchBilling(DONATE_PRODUCT_ID)
    }

    override fun destroy() {
        billingClient.endConnection()
    }

    override fun viewIsReady() {}

    private fun initBillingProcessor() {
        billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(activity)
                .enablePendingPurchases()
                .setListener {
            billingResult, purchases ->
            if (billingResult?.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && purchases != null) {
                //purchase done
                view!!.showToast(R.string.thanks_for_donate)
            }
        }.build()

        billingClient.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
            override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult?) {
                if (billingResult?.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                     // **place of logs**
                    querySkuDetails() 
                }
            }

            override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                //if wrong
            }
        })
    }

    private fun launchBilling(skuId: String) {
        val billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                .setSkuDetails(skuDetailsMap[skuId])
                .build()
        billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, billingFlowParams)
    }

    private fun querySkuDetails() {
        val skuDetailsParamsBuilder = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
        val skuList = ArrayList<String>()
        skuList.add(DONATE_PRODUCT_ID)
        skuDetailsParamsBuilder.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP)
        billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(skuDetailsParamsBuilder.build()) { billingResult, skuDetailsList ->
            if (billingResult?.responseCode ==  BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                for (skuDetails in skuDetailsList!!) {
                    skuDetailsMap[skuDetails.sku] = skuDetails
                }
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val DONATE_PRODUCT_ID = "donate"
    }
}
```

In "**place of logs**", i checked **billingResult.responseCode = -1; debugMessage = "Service connection is disconnected"**

I have no idea what to do. Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was using a lazy initialization.

That way, the Google Billing setup started immediately before the `launchBillingFlow` method call.

That caused the service to be disconnected and not ready yet for the precise moment the billing flow was started.

**I now start the BillingClient connection since the activity is started, and the flow works** as expected when requested by the user.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you are still having this problem, but I had it and debugging showed that the billing client was still using some old AIDL stuff I had not yet removed in the old com.android.vending package.  Once I removed all that code and gutted my app's support for the old stuff, I was able to proceed with the purchase without error.

Answer (score -2):

Faced such a problem. my decision is adding into application xml node

```
<!-- GOOGLE PLAY BILLING -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.android.billingclient.api.ProxyBillingActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

Comment: This is just a regular activity. What is unique about it?